# How to implement Mask R-CNN on iOS application?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, coreml, image-masking

We are trying to find out a specific object in Image & based on our requirement we would like to mask that object. 
Right now we are using tensor flow to detect an object inside a picture. To mask an object I want to use Mask R-CNN, but I am not able to find any help for Mobile. There are no Models are available neither.PB files are available which I can directly use inside iOS application.

Here are a couple of links I found :
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/pull/306

Is there any way other than Mask R-CNN to mask an Image or to color particular object inside an Image.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* possible to run Mask R-CNN on mobile, but you'll probably have to implement many of the operations yourself. I've been doing this for a client on iOS and it involves writing several custom GPU kernels. As far as I can tell there is no easy plug-and-play option. (This is true for a lot of advanced models.)